# Do iota, generate, and a hand rolled loop all perform the same?

Tags: c++, performance, vector

Is there a performance difference between these three ways of populating a vector?

```
#include <vector>
#include <numeric>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iterator>

int main()
{
    std::vector<int> v(10);
    std::iota(v.begin(), v.end(), 0);

    std::vector<int> v2(10);
    int i = 0;
    std::generate(v2.begin(), v2.end(), [&i](){return i++; });

    std::vector<int> v3(10);
    i = 0;
    for (auto& j : v3)
    {
        j = i++;
    }

return 0;
}
```

I know that they all produce the same results, I am interested only to know if there is a speed difference for larger vectors. **Would the answer be different for a different type?**

Comment: @WhozCraig Don't they all value initialize 10 elements?

Comment: @juanchopanza actually, yea, they do, now that I stare at them all. I would have `reserve()`ed and back-inserted the `generate_n`, which is what threw me to the latter inefficiency. You're absolutely right. Really need to stop reading SO on a sunday. Thanks for keeping me honest. dropping prior comment.

Comment: Anyway, I can't find anything in the standard that would give a performance advantage to any of the three variants. If there is one, it would be implementation dependent. Of course, for user defined types the use of pre-increment might conceivably give `iota` an advantage.

Comment: @WhozCraig: I thought that `reserve()` and `std::back_inserter()` could do well but it seems in practice it only pays off for really large vectors (trying on my Mac using recent versions of gcc and clang with -O3). Most likely, the check against the capacity and faffing about with the vector's size kill the performance of the `reserve()` approach: they'd require a customized version of the algorithms which avoids these costs in a smart way.

Comment: @DietmarKühl I'm of the same opinion. I primarily use it for vectors of objects with non-default construction or for very large vectors regardless of type. Usually I'm not that interested in the performance of such an artifact unless it is a *very* critical algorithm (which perhaps this is).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The proper way to find out is to measure and/or compare the generated code, of course. Since `std::vector<T>` uses contiguous memory for objects of type `T` compilers are likely to see through all 3 versions of the loops and generate near identical code. Also, there is pretty little a smart implementation can do for the specific algorithms in your setup. Things would be different, e.g., when using `std::deque<T>` where algorithms *could* process segments individually to improve performances (I'm not aware of any implementation which actually does so).

In case performance is you biggest concern and you are using large vectors, you might want to *not* create a large vector initially as this will probably touch all the memory although it is about to be overwritten. Instead, you'd construct and empty vector, `reserve()` sufficient memory, and then use a suitable target iterator (e.g., `std::back_inserter(v)`). The approaches would need to be changed suitably, though. When constructing the object in the algorithm, the algoriths actually *can* apply some smarts which a naive loop using, e.g., `push_back()`s or a suitable appending iterator probably doesn't apply: since the algoirthms can see how many objects they are going to create, they can hoist the check against the capacity out of the loop (although it needs some special access through the iterator type). Even if there is no optimization in the algorithm I would expect that doing a single pass over the vector has a much bigger benefit for performance than any tweaks in the algorithms.

Answer (score 10):

We can look at the output assembly (I used [gcc.godbolt.org](http://gcc.godbolt.org/) , gcc -03, with your code) :

1) First version, with `std::iota` :

```
main:
    sub rsp, 8
    mov edi, 40
    call    operator new(unsigned long)
    mov DWORD PTR [rax], 0
    mov DWORD PTR [rax+4], 1
    mov rdi, rax
    mov DWORD PTR [rax+8], 2
    mov DWORD PTR [rax+12], 3
    mov DWORD PTR [rax+16], 4
    mov DWORD PTR [rax+20], 5
    mov DWORD PTR [rax+24], 6
    mov DWORD PTR [rax+28], 7
    mov DWORD PTR [rax+32], 8
    mov DWORD PTR [rax+36], 9
    call    operator delete(void*)
    xor eax, eax
    add rsp, 8
    ret
```

2) Version with `std::generate` and the Lambda :

```
main:
    sub rsp, 8
    mov edi, 40
    call    operator new(unsigned long)
    mov DWORD PTR [rax], 0
    mov DWORD PTR [rax+4], 1
    mov rdi, rax
    mov DWORD PTR [rax+8], 2
    mov DWORD PTR [rax+12], 3
    mov DWORD PTR [rax+16], 4
    mov DWORD PTR [rax+20], 5
    mov DWORD PTR [rax+24], 6
    mov DWORD PTR [rax+28], 7
    mov DWORD PTR [rax+32], 8
    mov DWORD PTR [rax+36], 9
    call    operator delete(void*)
    xor eax, eax
    add rsp, 8
    ret
```

3) And the last version, with hand written loop :

```
main:
    sub rsp, 8
    mov edi, 40
    call    operator new(unsigned long)
    mov DWORD PTR [rax], 0
    mov DWORD PTR [rax+4], 1
    mov rdi, rax
    mov DWORD PTR [rax+8], 2
    mov DWORD PTR [rax+12], 3
    mov DWORD PTR [rax+16], 4
    mov DWORD PTR [rax+20], 5
    mov DWORD PTR [rax+24], 6
    mov DWORD PTR [rax+28], 7
    mov DWORD PTR [rax+32], 8
    mov DWORD PTR [rax+36], 9
    call    operator delete(void*)
    xor eax, eax
    add rsp, 8
    ret
```

---

**Conclusion :**

As expected, all three generate the same assembly (all unrolled) with a decent compiler, optimizations enabled.

So no, there is no performance difference.

---

**Note:**

I did the test of comparing assemblies with vectors large enough to not have unrolled loops (I don't know GCC heuristics, but it started for sizes >~ 15).

In that case the assembly is *still identical* for the all 3 cases, I won't copy the output here since it doesn't bring much to the answer, but the thing is that compilers are *really* very good at optimizing this kind of code.

Comment: +1 worth noting a 64-bit assembler and a decent optimizer will crunch this down to a significantly smaller amount of `mov`s (half in fact). [**see listing here**](http://pastebin.com/CHb3FDTB).

Answer (score -2):

You forgot to mention one more standard algorithm - algorithm `std::for_each`.

For example

```
std::vector<int> v4(10);
int i = 0;
std::for_each(v4.begin(), v4.end(), [&i]( int &item ){ item = i++; } );
```

There is no any essential difference between the algorithms and the range-based for statement. In fact they duplicate each other. For example the range-based for statement uses the same methods begin() and end().

So it would be better to pay attention to expressiveness. In this case I would prefer `std::iota`.

Also maybe it would be interesting to read about [my proposal on algorithm std::iota](http://cpp.forum24.ru/?1-3-0-00000046-000-0-0-1352203696) Though the genetal text is written in Russian you will be able to read it using for example google service translate.